# ¿Cómo hacer estas validaciones correctamente?

Tags: java

Bueno tengo otra pregunta como seria para que cuando uno ingrese una palabra que no es, no salgan todos los else.

Por ejemplo, si yo escribo cualquier cosa en la parte de "amo a maton" saldrian como 4 `"chuta" + nombre + " te equivocaste, todo tu culpa"`. ¿Cómo sería que sólo salga uno de estos y no todos? O sea, que el coso salen cuatro e incluso el `"Bueno hasta la proxima, apagando...."`?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Puto{ 
  public static void main(String args[]){ 
 
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    String nombre = ""; 
    String cancion = "";
    String partl = "";
    String partll = "";
    String partlll = "";
    String partllll = "";
    String finall = "";

    System.out.println("¿Cuál es tu nombre?");
    nombre = in.nextLine();
    
    System.out.println("¿Cuál cancion quiere cantar señor " + nombre + "?");
    cancion = in.nextLine();
    
    if (cancion.equalsIgnoreCase("Puto")){
      System.out.println("Okey esa cancion si esta en nuestro sistema comienze usted:");
      partl = in.nextLine(); 
   }  else {
       System.out.println("Esa cancion aun no esta en el programa");
    }
    if (partl.equalsIgnoreCase("Amo a maton")){
     System.out.println("Matarile al maricón");
     partll = in.nextLine();
   } else {
       System.out.println("chuta" + nombre + " te equivocaste, todo tu culpa");
    }
    if (partll.equalsIgnoreCase("Y que quiere este hijo de puta?")){
     System.out.println("Quiere llorar, quiere llorar");
     partlll = in.nextLine();
   } else {
       System.out.println("chuta " + nombre + " te equivocaste, todo tu culpa");
   }
   if (partlll.equalsIgnoreCase("Amo a maton")){
     System.out.println("Matarile al maricon");
     partllll = in.nextLine();
   } else {
       System.out.println("chuta " + nombre + " te equivocaste, todo tu culpa");
   } 
   if (partllll.equalsIgnoreCase("Y que quiere este hocicon?")){
     System.out.println("Quiere llorar, quiere llorar");
     System.out.println("Bien hecho eso es todo, algo mas?");
     finall = in.nextLine(); 
   } else {
       System.out.println("chuta " + nombre + " te equivocaste, todo tu culpa");     
   } 
   System.out.println("Bueno hasta la proxima, apagando....");
 }
}
```

Comment: Tus variables `partl` tienen como valor un `String` vacío. Si nunca se les asigna un valor en los `if` esperados, la comparación entre un string vacío y cualquier otro string en tus if va a dar `false` como resultado.

Comment: Yo creo que la mejor solución será utilizar `if else` anidados o un `switch`.

Comment: @MauricioContreras es la letra de una canción.

Comment: por dios.. ES UNA CANCION!!!!

Comment: Hola Mati, en cada **else** en la linea que va después del **System.out.println** agrega **return;**, así termina la ejecución del programa, sin repetir mensajes.

Answer (score 1):

hola mati soy nuevo en java pero puedo darte una posible solucion a lo que buscas, he implementado el uso de **switch** y también un **if y else**

Aqui te dejo el codigo, espero sea de ayuda:

```
package practicasjava;

import java.util.Scanner;


public class LKiller {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        String nombre;
        String cancion;
        String part1;
        String part2;
        String part3;
        String part4;
        String condicionFinal;
        //Le pongo entre comillas en vez de null para que no imprima null y solo vacio
        String textoCancion = "";

        System.out.println("¿Cuál es tu nombre?");
        nombre = in.nextLine();

        System.out.println("¿Cuál cancion quiere cantar señor " + nombre + "?");
        cancion = in.nextLine();
        
        //Se agrego un switch para evaluar la cancion
        switch (cancion) {
            case "Puto": //En caso de que el usuario escriba la cancion correcta 
                System.out.println("Okey esa cancion si esta en nuestro sistema comienze usted:");
                part1 = in.nextLine();
                if (part1.equalsIgnoreCase("Amo a maton")) {
                    System.out.println("Matarile al maricon");
                    part2 = in.nextLine();
                    if (part2.equalsIgnoreCase("Y que quiere este hijo de puta?")) {
                        System.out.println("Quiere llorar, quiere llorar");
                        part3 = in.nextLine();
                        if (part3.equalsIgnoreCase("Amo a maton")) {
                            System.out.println("Matarile al maricon");
                            part4 = in.nextLine();
                            if (part4.equalsIgnoreCase("Y que quiere este hocicon?")) {
                                System.out.println("Quiere llorar, quiere llorar");
                                System.out.println("Bien hecho eso es todo, algo mas?");
                                condicionFinal = in.nextLine();
                                //Si el usuario dice que no desea algo mas, se imprime "Bueno hasta la proxima, apagando...."
                                if (condicionFinal.equalsIgnoreCase("no")) {
                                    System.out.println("Bueno hasta la proxima, apagando....");
                                }
                            } else {
                                System.out.println("Chuta " + nombre + " te equivocaste, todo tu culpa");
                            }
                        } else {
                            System.out.println("Chuta " + nombre + " te equivocaste, todo tu culpa");
                        }
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Chuta " + nombre + " te equivocaste, todo tu culpa");
                    }
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Chuta " + nombre + " te equivocaste, todo tu culpa");
                }
                break;
            //Si el usuario escribe una cancion que no esta en lista le bota este mensaje    
            default:
                textoCancion = "Esta cancion aun no esta en el programa";
                
        }
        //Aqui se imprime la linea del default
        System.out.println(textoCancion);
    }
}
```